# My promises no longer working in jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-deferred

This code snippet worked in 1.7.2 with both success/error callbacks as well as promises style callbacks. With 1.8.2 the success/error callbacks still work but the promises do not. My hunch is that the `return dfd.promise(jqXHR);` line is the problem but im not certain.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {

    // Don't infinitely recurse
    originalOptions._retry = isNaN(originalOptions._retry)
        ? Common.auth.maxExpiredAuthorizationRetries
        : originalOptions._retry - 1;

    // set up to date authorization header with every request
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", Common.auth.getAuthorizationHeader());

    // save the original error callback for later
    if (originalOptions.error)
        originalOptions._error = originalOptions.error;

    // overwrite *current request* error callback
    options.error = $.noop();

    // setup our own deferred object to also support promises that are only invoked
    // once all of the retry attempts have been exhausted
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    jqXHR.done(dfd.resolve);

    // if the request fails, do something else yet still resolve
    jqXHR.fail(function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        if (jqXHR.status === 401 && originalOptions._retry > 0) {

            // refresh the oauth credentials for the next attempt(s)
            // (will be stored and returned by Common.auth.getAuthorizationHeader())
            Common.auth.handleUnauthorized();

            // retry with our modified
            $.ajax(originalOptions).then(dfd.resolve, dfd.reject);

        } else {
            // add our _error callback to our promise object
            if (originalOptions._error)
                dfd.fail(originalOptions._error);
            dfd.rejectWith(jqXHR, args);
        }
    });

    // NOW override the jqXHR's promise functions with our deferred
    return dfd.promise(jqXHR);
});
```

**Update**: Here is my ajax request that fails:

```
$.ajax({
        url: someFunctionToGetUrl(),
        // works
        //success: callback,
        //error: ajaxErrorHandler
    }).then(
        [callback],
        [errorback, ajaxErrorHandler]
    );
};
```

Comment: Are your requests synchronous? If so, it won't work with `jqXHR`. From docs: "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks."

Comment: No, added my ajax request in post

Comment: Are you familiar with Chrome debugger? >.<
Your post can be answered by people who: 1 dealth with the exact same thing (or do the research). 2 have the patience and will to setup an example to investigate. So if you'd provide an answer it would be helpful.

Comment: I'll provide an answer as soon as I find one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** This is a documentation bug, but the behavior is by design.  The api changed such that `deferred.then` now behaves like [`deferred.pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) and no longer allows arrays to be passed in, but the documentation hasn't been updated to reflect that.

Related bugs:

- **github:** [deferred.then now behaves like deferred.pipe but the documentation is stale](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/159)
- **jQuery Bug Tracker:** [Ticket #12765: deferred.then([SuccessArrayFuncs],failFunc) does not work as described](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12765)

The workaround I describe at the end of my original answer below still applies.

---

**Original answer:**

It looks like a jQuery bug to me.  If you pass in a single function reference as the first argument, it works, but not if you pass in an array of functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/tunDH/

But, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) says an array of functions is just fine:

> **doneCallbacks**   A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is resolved.

And, you are right.  It does work with jQuery 1.7: http://jsfiddle.net/tunDH/1/

A workaround would be to wrap all your function calls inside a single function, instead of inside an array:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: someFunctionToGetUrl(), 
    // works 
    //success: callback, 
    //error: ajaxErrorHandler 
}).then( 
    function(){
        callback1.apply(this, arguments);
        callback2.apply(this, arguments);
    }, 
    [errorback, ajaxErrorHandler] 
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tunDH/2/

You'll probably need to do the same thing with the error callbacks, but I didn't test that.